# New Plugin (Link) at CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

today i want to add a new plugin in our CKEDITOR of our PIM System.
Therefore i load the "Link" Plugin from CKEEditor.

First step - i include the plugin to my CKE-Installation under the following path:

> ckeditor\js\ckeditor\plugins\link

After that i try to change my "ckeeditor.Config.js"

It looks like the following config:

```
    var CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = (function() {


     var module = {};

     var configs = {

    'default': {
    toolbar: [
        [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','Undo','Redo'],
                ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv',
          '-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
                ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
                ['Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar'],
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript',
                'Source','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview', 'Print','-','Templates', 
          'SpellChecker', 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt'],
        ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 
        'HiddenField'],
        ['RemoveFormat','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl'],   
         ['PageBreak','Iframe','Styles','Format','Font','FontSize', 'TextColor','BGColor', 
                'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About']   
      ]

    }
  };

  module.getConfiguration = function(args) {
    return configs['default'];
  };

  return module;


}());
```

By reading some posts i found out that i have to add the following code to the config data

> config.extraPlugins = 'link';

Can someone tell my wherer i have to add the "config.extraPlugins ='link';
I have already tried out many places in the code, but without any success.

Have someone the same problems? Have i overlooked something?

Thanks in advance
Tim

Comment: Has nobody any idea? How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Directly in your config.js configuration can be. Modify this code:
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config)

You less a parameter, plus this parameter and then configure:
Config.extraPlugins = 'link'

I also have a custom plug-in, is this done.